# Text Alignment within \psframebox

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I'm trying to represent the functionning of a device. It has 2 ports, and make computations on the payload of a data packet.

I use `pst-node` from the `PSTricks` suite to realise it, b I came across some problems...

1. I'd like to have a data packet made up of 2 parts : `header` and `payload`. But the `y` in `Payload` causes a bad alignment of the two words. Moreover, it messes up the whole dimensions of the `\psframebox`. The 2 packets drawn features the 2 problems.
2. I'd like to have the `Payload` box "concatenated" to the `Header` box. I tried using the `[tl]` and `[tr]` otpions for the `rput` command, but it's messed up when it comes to binding boxes... Moreover, as the `[cr]` and `[cl]` doesn't exist, the data packet boxes aren't vertically aligned with the other (`Process` and `Port 1`)

My MWE hereunder summarizes all the problems I have :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=FR, per-mode=symbol, abbreviations]{siunitx}



\begin{document}
\bgroup
%\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](-5, 1)(13, 6)
    \rput[c](-4,4.5){\rnode{priv}{Port 1}}
    \rput[cl](12,2.5){\rnode{publ}{Port 1}}

    \rput[c](5.5,4.5){\rnode{ipsec}{\psframebox[framesep=10pt,cornersize=absolute,linearc=0.2, linecolor=red]{\textcolor{red}{Process}}}}


    \rput[tl](2,4.5){\rnode{header1}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Header}}}
    \rput[tr](2,4.5){\rnode{payload1}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Payload 1}}}


    \psframe[framearc=.3,linestyle=dashed, linecolor=black!40](-1.5, 1.5)(9.5,5.75)


    \rput[c](5.6,2.5){\rnode{header2}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Header}}}
    \rput[c](7.25, 2.5){\rnode{payload2}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Paload 2}}}

    \ncline{<->}{payload1}{ipsec}
    \ncangle[angleA=-90, angleB=180, armB=0, linearc=.5]{<->}{header1}{header2}
    \ncangle[angleB=90, armB=0, linearc=.5]{<->}{ipsec}{payload2}
    \ncline{<->}{payload2}{publ}
    \ncline{<->}{header1}{priv}

\end{pspicture}
%}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

And its output : 
[image: MWE Ootput]

Any ideas on how to right this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that ok that you have a straight line from Port1 to Process??

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=FR, per-mode=symbol, abbreviations]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5, 1)(13, 6)
\rput[c](-4,4.5){\rnode{priv}{Port 1}}
\rput[cl](12,2.5){\rnode{publ}{Port 1}}
\rput[c](5.5,4.5){\rnode{ipsec}{\psframebox[framesep=10pt,
        cornersize=absolute,linearc=0.2, linecolor=red]{\textcolor{red}{Process}}}}
\rput[l](2,4.5){\rnode{header1}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Header\vphantom{y}}}}
\rput[r](2,4.5){\rnode{payload1}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Payload 1}}}
\psframe[framearc=.3,linestyle=dashed, linecolor=black!40](-1.5, 1.5)(9.5,5.75)
\rput[r](7,2.5){\rnode{header2}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Header}}}
\rput[l](7,2.5){\rnode{payload2}{\psframebox[framesep=4pt]{Paload 2}}}
\ncline{<->}{payload1}{priv}
\ncangle[angleA=-90,angleB=180, armB=0,linearc=.5]{<->}{header1}{header2}
\ncangle[angleB=90, armB=0, linearc=.5]{<->}{ipsec}{payload2}
\ncline{<->}{payload2}{publ}
\ncline{<->}{header1}{ipsec} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The arrow from `Port` has to stop at `Payload1`...

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? It's easier to do with `psmatrix`.

Note you don't have to load all `PSTricks` related packages, as `pstricks-add` already loads `pstricks, pst-plot, pst-node, pst-3d, pst-math` and `multido`. Also, the option `usenames` for `xcolor` is unnecessary, as it is the default nowadays. I loaded the `x11names` option, as it defines may more colours than `dvipsnames`.

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,}%
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\def\mylength{\dimexpr1.5cm + \pslinewidth\relax}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hspace*{-\mylength}}
\def\pscolhookv{\hspace*{-\mylength}}
\newlength\mysep
\psset{framesep=4pt, arrowinset=0.15, linejoin=1}
\begin{psmatrix}%
    [name=priv] Port 1 & [name=payload1] \psframebox{Payload 1}& [name=header1] \psframebox{Header\vphantom{y}} & [name=ipsec]\makebox[0pt]{\psframebox[framesep=10pt,cornersize=absolute,linearc=0.2, linecolor=IndianRed3]{\eqmakebox[ips]{\color{IndianRed3}Process}}}& & \\ %
    & & & [name=header2] \psframebox{Header\vphantom{y}} & [name=payload2] \psframebox{Payload 2} &
    [name=publ] Port1
    \setlength{\mysep}{\dimexpr\eqboxwidth{ips}/2+10pt +\pslinewidth\relax}
    \ncline[nodesepB=\mysep]{<->}{header1}{ipsec}
    \ncangle[angleA=-90, angleB=180, armB=0, linearc=.5]{<->}{header1}{header2}
    \ncangle[angleB=90, armB=0, linearc=.3,nodesepA=\mysep]{<->}{ipsec}{payload2}
    \pnode[-1.5,1](payload1){PL1}
    \pnode[1.5,-1](payload2){PL2}
    \psframe[framearc=.3,linestyle=dashed, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3](PL1)(PL2)
    \psset{nodesepB=3pt}
    \ncline{<->}{payload2}{publ}
    \ncline{<->}{payload1}{priv}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One `)` is missing at the line `\setlength{\mysep}{\dimexpr(\eqboxwidth{ips}/2+10pt +\pslinewidth\relax}`. Is it after the `/2` ?

Comment: I will wait until Herbert's solution to mark the question answered, as it's the closest to what I tried...

Comment: @Eisenheim: I've added the dashed frame that I had forgotten.